# Determiners of Quantity and Count Nouns: What is wrong with saying, "Joan drank hardly any sodas"?

Tags: grammar

My GMAT book (GMAT Ultimate Grammar) says it is incorrect in an exercise where we fill in the blank of a sentence based on choices of possible determiners of quantity. It says you cannot use hardly any to complete Joan drank ____ sodas. However, at Walden University's website it says hardly any can work with plural count nouns and non-count nouns.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please provide the full context: which book? What is the topic of the lesson? Is this an exercise or an example from text? I agree that there are no obvious problems, but there may be situations where this phrasing would not be desired. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: Not all Phds who write this stuff agree. Technically, Joan probably drank hardly any soda [because with an s that would mean 2 or 3 rather than 10 or 12]. That said, she may have eaten hardly any peas. In other words, size may matter.

Comment: *Hardly any sodas* does sound odd to me, but I don't know what the precise grammatical rule about that would be. Maybe if the noun can be non-countable or countable, the non-countable is preferred?

Comment: Regardless, good luck. Tests like that are more about reading the writers' minds and knowing obscure vocabulary and arcane, pedantic (and not always objectively correct) "rules" than anything useful.

Comment: @Kevin - If at a party you sent me to check on the beverage situation and I checked the cooler and reported, “There are hardly any sodas left.” How would that sound to you?

Comment: @Jim yeah, that does sound reasonable.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯